# How to search videos using keywords with the YouTube data API in Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to search for videos related to a specific keyword using the YouTube data API and want to show them in a list view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to use the [Youtube Data Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). [Here is an example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252C%20snippet&maxResults=1&q=moon&type=video&_h=2&) of a request which returns a JSON response (1 video data).

To use the Data Api from Android, you can use an `HttpURLConnection` object, or use the [Youtube Data Api Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3), that's up to you.

Once you have retrieved the video's data from the Youtube Data Api. Use the [Youtube Player Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to display the videos. There is a demo app in the link.